# Import brownie cannot be resolved

Tags: brownie

I try running this script

```
from brownie import Token, accounts

def main():
return Token.deploy("Test Token", "TST", 18, 1e21, {'from': accounts[0]})
```

Then error message is an issue of finding brownie as import

```
    "resource": "/c:/Python/token/token/scripts/token.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingImports",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules",
            "path": "/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "diagnostic-severity-rules"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"brownie\" could not be resolved",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 13
```

Comment: Where is this error coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

Not very much info provided, but I'll just shoot whatever comes to my mind.

1. Do you have brownie installed? `brownie --version`
2. Did you initialize the project using `brownie init` ?
3. Do you have that Token.sol in `contracts` folder in your brownie project and has it been successfuly compiled using `brownie compile` before? You can check if it has been compiled in `./build/contracts/Token.json`

Comment: Thanks for this information. brownie will not work. When I try pip install eth-brownie it fails with error message of: pip failed to build package: cytoolz

Comment: Try to follow this thread if it solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875694/pip-failed-to-build-package-cytoolz

Comment: This fixed some the brownie issue.

Comment: please add your Token.sol code into your original question if its part of your problem

Comment: from brownie import Token, accounts
def main():
    return Token.deploy("Test Token", "TST", 18, 1e21, {'from': accounts[0]})

Comment: unable to find Token

Comment: You are clearly missing entire `Token.sol` smart contract. Brownie doesn't have anything called `Token`, you need to program it yourself. You can use this documentation: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20

Comment: I deleted and uninstalled Python, Brownie, Ganache and reloaded. Now Brownie init does not work. There must be a standard way to load the files or align paths to find files. Any suggestion on the method, as this should be the easy part.